# Scraping html using [jsdom + qs]

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, jsdom

I'm new to using jsdom and querystring. I'm trying to scrape a page for all of the soundcloud `track_id`'s within all of the iframe html tags. The code below logs `undefined` because the first iframe is not a soundcloud player.

How do I...

1. Modify the code to retrieve all of the iframe instances
2. Check if `http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F` or just `soundcloud` is present using jsdom/qs. (I can use an if string contains string type of js test, but I figure there is a better way using jsdom/qs).

   ```
   jsdom.env({
    html: 'A_URL',
    scripts: [
      'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
    ],
    done: function(errors, window) {
     var $ = window.$;
     var src = $('iframe').attr('src');
     var aRes = qs.parse(decodeURIComponent(url.parse(src).query)).url.split('/');
     var track_id = aRes[aRes.length-1];

    console.log("track_id =", track_id);
    }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe').each(function(index, element) {
  if (element.attr['src'].match(/soundcloud/)) {
    // do your stuff
    return false; // if there's only one relevant iframe
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this needs an extra ')' after soundcloud argument.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. How do I check if 'src' exists in the iframe?

Comment: Missing paren fixed in edit. Normally an `iframe` would always have a `src`, but if there's some case where it might not, just change the test to `if (element.attr[src] && ...`.

Comment: I keep getting `src is not defined` when I know there is 10+ iframes with `src` on the page.

Comment: Is that after executing the original line: `var src = $('iframe').attr('src');` or did you change your code? (note that if it's the original and you have more than one iframe, `src` will be set to the "src" attribute of the first one (or `undefined` if it doesn't have one). That's why you need to use `$('iframe').each()`; `$('iframe')` can return a jQuery object matching multiple elements, and if you apply a method such as `attr` to such an object it only deals with the first element in the collection).

Comment: No I removed that line. The only code I have in the `.each` function is `if (element.attr['src'])`.